# pseudo-Anosov surface in three manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

A surface $S$ in a three manifold $M$ is  pseudo-Anosov means if there exists a homeomorphism
$f$ over $M$ for which $S$ is $f$ invariant and $f$ is a pseudo-Anosov on $S$. For example, 
$M$---- any surface bundle over circle with pseudo-Anosov monodromy map;
$S$---- a fiber (surface).

**Question: Which three manifolds admit a pseudo-Anosov surface?**

**More subtle, if $M$ is irreducible, does the example(s)
above contain all cases? Moreover, is the following true?: $M$ admits a pseudo-Anosov surface iff 
there exists a prime factor of $M$ admits a pseudo-Anosov surface?**

This question is motivated by [link text](http://aimsciences.org/journals/pdfs.jsp?paperID=6086&mode=full). In this paper, the authors tell us: if $S$ is torus, $f$
is Anosov and $M$ is irreducible, $M$ must be one of the following 3 cases: 
(1) the 3-torus $T^3$;
(2) the mapping torus of -id;
(3) the mapping tori of hyperbolic automorphisms of $T^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For genus greater than one, there are lots of Pseudo-Anosov mapping classes that extend over handlebodies, so you can build lots of examples that are not of the types listed above.
Here is a specific example:
D.D. Long "Pseudo-Anosov maps which extend over two handlebodies" Proceedings of Edinburgh Society(1990) 33, 181-190

There is recent work of Biringer, Johnson, and Minsky  characterizing when  a power of a pseudo-anosov extends over a handlebody: http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0021

Comment: Thanks Frohman. So it seems all ? of the subtle part of my question.
I even don't know whether there exists a three manifold without P-A
surface. PS, for Anosov case, the second ? of the subtle part  is a question in the paper which motivate my question.  


Comment: I don't know what the answer to the first part of your question is.  I think its more subtle than the second part.

Comment: Sorry, "So it seems all ? of the subtle part of my question" should be "So it seems the answers of all ? of the subtle part of my question are negative"